# Problem in launching MATLAB - will only run as root

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, launcher, sudo, matlab

I installed MATLAB in `/usr/local`. Now when I try to launch it normally from dash or by typing `matlab` in terminal, it starts up and then gives an error that says:

```
Internal error: No write permission on directory...
```

But it launches when I run it using `sudo`. I don't want to run it as root.
I give a recursive write permission to .matlab directory with `sudo chmod -R 776 /home/uname/.matlab` command. Then I tried launch matlab from terminal using command `matlab`. It terminated with massage :`MATLAB is exiting because of fatal error`.

Comment: Have you checked the ownership and permissions of the directory in question (perhaps `~/.matlab`)? The problem is almost certainly **because** you have run it using `sudo` - see [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications).

Comment: I launched matlab using the command `sudo -H matlab`. But I could not notice any difference.

Comment: Can I create a launcher icon for matlab?

Comment: Running with `sudo -H` now won't help: you need to check the ownership and permissions on the directory mentioned in the error message (which you forgot to include): it likely wouldn't hurt to run `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.matlab`

Comment: I ran `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.matlab`. But it gives an error: `chown: missing operand after ‘$USER:$USER/.matlab’`.

Comment: You need a space between the `$USER:$USER` and the `~/.matlab` - also make sure you include the `~`, if in doubt (or you can't find it on your keyboard) then use `sudo chown  -R  $USER:$USER  $HOME/.matlab`

Comment: Wow, it worked. Thank You @ steeldriver for your valuable advices.

Answer (score 1):

`chmod` is just change mode so that you can update your read/write/delete permissions. `chown` is like a main-gate or encapsulation. Even though, you had

```
chmod a+rwx <your .matlab folder>/-R
```

it doesn't launch `matlab` because you can't reach inside unless you take ownership of that `.matlab` folder. So,

change the shell as a root, and take ownership as below:

```
root@upg:~# chown username:groupname <your_matlab_folder>
```

Ownership is giving system to access (`chown` is your answer here). Giving read/write/delete actions is using `chmod`.